# Get file link on ng-click event selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome

Hi is there any way to get link for file, when I click on Download button browser start to download file.

I have following html button tag.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="vm.handleClick(vm.item[1])">Download</button>
```

When I use this it only download file, is there any way to get link from ng-click event?

```
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", webElement);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get link for file when I click on Download button"? Do you want to access the downloaded file in C#?

Comment: @GregBurghardt No I tried that but it didn't worked well, I managed to read json data from site and there were links which I needed, I doubt that there is better solution when you have angular ng model.